# IIS 7/ASP.NET WebForms application on Multi Processor server getting confused? Column '{dataColumn}' does not belong to table {dataTable}

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, webforms, windows-server-2008

We have been working on our application for about a year now and today we performed a manual stress test with about 70 users.  Our SQL server and WinForms application ran smooth, however, once the web application hit around 20 users, the server started acting strange.

One error that we received multiple times was when a stored procedure executed and loaded a DataTable, it would report "Column '{dataColumn}' does not belong to table {dataTable}".  The odd thing was that after you received the error, you could refresh the page and the error would go away and the page would work correctly.

One of our questions is would this be caused by having IIS running on a multi processor server?  If so, is there a server setting or a code modification that can resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that we may have resolved this error by removing the Shared/Static access modifier on the functions that use database functionality.  Will follow up after more testing.